# how can i prevent from clicking twice in the same tile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a game and im trying to figure out how to prevent my X to be deleted when clicking twice in the same tile right now i can move my "X" around but it get's deleted if i click twice. ive tried boolean but im terrible with them . is there a way to do it with boolean or anything else ? Im a beginner at school.

```js
var clique1fois = false;
var clique = null;
var aClique = false;

function deplacerPion(x) {
  if (aClique == true) {
    x.innerHTML = clique.innerHTML;
    clique.innerHTML = "";
    aClique = false;
    clique.style.border = "1px solid black";
    clique.style.height = "80px";
    clique.style.width = "80px";
  } else {
    x.style.border = "3px solid red";
    x.style.width = "76px";
    x.style.height = "76px";
    clique = x;
    aClique = true;
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#titre {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div id="titre">Jeu de table</div>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="deplacerPion(this)">X</td>
    <td onclick="deplacerPion(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but i do not know the game mechanics. Can you explain what should happens when you click on table cels?

Comment: add a class, see if the class exists. If it does, ignore the click

Answer (score 1):

Instead of boolean, you can simply add/remove a class that shows/hides the X.

In my answer below, on click, first we check to see if any Xs are active, if so remove the active. Then add the active class to the X within the clicked cell.

```js
function deplacerPion(x) {
  let active = document.querySelector(".icon.active");
  if (active) {
    active.classList.remove("active")
  }
  x.querySelector(".icon").classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
td {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#titre {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}

.icon {
  display: none;
}

.active.icon {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="titre">Jeu de table</div>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="deplacerPion(this)">
      <div class="icon active">X</div>
    </td>
    <td onclick="deplacerPion(this)">
      <div class="icon">X</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```